# How can I delete or uninstall Avalonia from Winforms C# Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, nuget, avaloniaui

I had installed Avalonia from nuget but did not use it so now I want to remove it from my project.

What i tried:

- I Tried uninstalling from Nuget Package manager.

  ->  But What happens when i click uninstall is Just a prompt to confirm then when i click OK Some messages are printed in the console telling it is being uninstalled but then nothing changes.(It remains installed)
- As suggested by another answer I tried modifying the packages.config but no effect either.(Visual Studio Tells to Restore the missing packages!)

How can i remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit csproj file and managed .targets file, then remove the `PackageReference` section.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Avalonia" Version="X.X.X" />
    ...  
  </ItemGroup>
```